# Make Package Expolorer Appear in Eclipse (Window > Show View is not working)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package-explorer

I am using Eclipse for Android programming. Somehow (I probably accidentally closed it), the package explorer (usually on the left side), isn't there anymore. How do I get it back in the same position? I have tried Window > Show View > Package Explorer and it did nothing. I also tried Window > Open Perspective > Java Browsing and it opens the Package Explorer, but in the wrong position and it also opens a bunch of other unwanted things. I am in the Java perspective now.

How do I get the Package Explorer to appear back on the left side?

Comment: On your top right, switch to Java perspective, then you should see the package explorer icon aligned on the left edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right-click on the java perspective and say close.
Then open it again from the 'Open Perspective' like had done originally.
I had done this on occasion when Eclipse was misbehaving.  And it should bring the default views back in.  Usually quicker for me then to remember how to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "Package Explorer" Move->View